# TypeConverter.IsValid() uses current thread culture but TypeConverter.ConvertFrom() doesn't?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

It seems that `TypeConverter.IsValid()` uses the current thread culture but `TypeConverter.ConvertFrom()` doesn't.

This makes it pretty useless to use `TypeConverter.IsValid()` with the `DateTime` type unless you are in the invariant culture. Indeed, it seems to be a bug.

**Does anyone know how to make `TypeConverter.IsValid()` use the current culture?**

The following code demonstrates the problem.

It uses two strings, one in DD/MM/YYYY format and one in MM/DD/YYYY format.

The first part of the test is done in the Invariant Culture. It demonstrates that  `TypeConverter.IsValid()` returns true for the MM/DD/YYYY string and that you can use `TypeConverter.ConvertFrom()` to convert that string to a `DateTime`.

The first part also demonstrates that `TypeConverter.IsValid()` returns false for the DD/MM/YYYY string.

For the second part, I change the current culture "en-GB" which uses "DD/MM/YYYY" dates.

I would now expect the `IsValid()` results to be reversed, but it returns the same as before for the two strings. So it says that the MM/DD/YYYY string is valid.

However - and this is the important bit - if you try to use `TypeConverter.ConvertFrom()` to actually convert the string which `TypeConverter.IsValid()` said was ok, you will get an exception.

Is there a way to work around this?

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        void Run()
        {
            // Start off with the US culture, which has MM/DD/YYYY date format.

            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

            var dateConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(DateTime));
            var goodDateString = "07/19/1961";
            var badDateString  = "19/07/1961";

            test(dateConverter, goodDateString, "DateTime"); // Says it's good.
            test(dateConverter, badDateString, "DateTime");  // Says it's bad.

            var dateTimeValue = (DateTime) dateConverter.ConvertFrom(goodDateString);

            Console.WriteLine("dateTimeValue = " + dateTimeValue);
            Console.WriteLine();

            // Now lets change the current culture to the UK, which has DD/MM/YYYY date format.

            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");
            dateConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(DateTime));

            test(dateConverter, goodDateString, "DateTime"); // Still says it's good.
            test(dateConverter, badDateString, "DateTime");  // Still says it's bad.

            // TypeConverter.IsValid(badDateString) returns false, so we shouldn't be able to convert it.
            // Well, we can, like so:

            dateTimeValue = (DateTime)dateConverter.ConvertFrom(badDateString); // Shouldn't work according to "IsValid()"
            Console.WriteLine("dateTimeValue (bad) = " + dateTimeValue);        // But this is printed ok.

            // TypeConverter.IsValid(goodDateString) returns true, so we can convert it right?
            // Well, no. This now throws an exception, even though "IsValid()" returned true for the same string.

            dateTimeValue = (DateTime)dateConverter.ConvertFrom(goodDateString); // This throws an exception.
        }

        void test(TypeConverter converter, string text, string type)
        {
            if (converter.IsValid(text))
                Console.WriteLine("\"" + text + "\" IS a valid " + type);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("\"" + text + "\" is NOT a valid " + type);
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            new Program().Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From memory, "no" leaps to mind. But I seem to recall there are a whole number of issues with the `IsValid` API and it not working very well in all cases. It may be necessary just to try the convert and see if it works.

Comment: @MarcGravell Aye, that would seem to be the appropriate action - just avoid using `IsValid()` altogether.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a flaw in TypeConverter.IsValid().  A type converter is culture-aware, its virtual ConvertFrom() method takes a CultureInfo argument.  You are using the non-virtual overload that doesn't take a CultureInfo so you'll get the conversion selected by CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.

TypeConverter.IsValid() does *not* have an overload that accepts a CultureInfo.  And flubs the CultureInfo it passes to the TypeConverter.ConvertFrom() method, it passes CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.

Hard to come up with a justification for this behavior.  Probably a bug that just got noticed too late to do anything about.  It certainly isn't fixable anymore.

The workaround is to do what IsValid() does but by specifying the correct culture.  First call CanConvertFrom(), then call ConvertFrom() in a try/catch block.

Comment: Ah thanks. You also anticipated another question I would have had: *`"Is it less efficient catch errors using the exceptions compared to using `IsValid()?"`* - but fortunately now I know it makes no difference.