# TypeDescriptor does not recongnise date

Tags: c#, typedescriptor

I'm having an ussue with the TypeDescriptor class.

I have a cookie which contains a date - the date is converted to a string and then back again using some helper methods.

One of my staple extension methods is used to do the conversion, however it throws a forced error because the date is not convertible back from a string.

Here's the message I output:

22/01/2015 14:29:15 could not be converted to DateTime

Looks like a DateTime to me!

The problem can be overcome by using `Convert.ToDateTime()`, so the code in general is ok. i also use it for dates elwhere with no problems to date.

The only difference is that I'm converting in the middle of a linq statement like this:

```
            Set = new SortedSet<TrackedItem>(set
                .Split(';')
                .Select(s =>
                {
                    var parts = s.Split(',');
                    return new TrackedItem(
                           parts[0].ConvertTo<int>(),
                           Convert.ToDateTime(parts[1]));
                }));
```

Any ideas?

```
    public static T ConvertTo<T>(this object obj, bool throwInvalid = false)
        where T : IConvertible
    {
        // Object does not require converting.
        if (obj is T) return (T)obj;

        // Determine if object can be converted. 
        var type = typeof(T);
        var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type);

        var isConvertible = converter != null && converter.IsValid(obj);

        var error = string.Format("'{0}' could not be converted to type {1}", obj, type.Name);

        // If no conversion is available, and defaults not allowed throw an error. 
        (!isConvertible && throwInvalid).ThrowTrue(error);

        // If the object is convertible, convert it, else return the default(T).
        return isConvertible ? (T)converter.ConvertFrom(obj) : default(T);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing from your date example that you're running in the `en-GB` culture. Unfortunately, to draw liberally from [this related q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16837774/typeconverter-isvalid-uses-current-thread-culture-but-typeconverter-convertfro), `IsValid` always uses `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` (US date format) to decide its answer. So when running in `en-GB` with a date such as your example, `IsValid` will return `false`; but `ConvertFrom`, which by default uses the current thread culture  will succeed!

Interestingly, [the latest docs for `IsValid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tez461eb.aspx) massively hedge the question of whether this is actually a bug:

> The `IsValid` method is used to validate a value within the type
>   rather than to determine if value can be converted to the given type.
>   For example, `IsValid` can be used to determine if a given value is
>   valid for an enumeration type.

So really you shouldn't be using `IsValid` here at all - you should be doing what the same docs go on to suggest:

> You can write your own `WillConvertSucceed` method by wrapping the
>   `ConvertTo` and `ConvertFrom` methods in exception blocks.

And in that method you can be sure to use the `CultureInfo` you actually care about.

Comment: Spot on Aakash - removed isvalid and everything works. Thanks for the very informative answer, it's very much appreciated.